# Deleting an object from an array and changing one of its properties simultaneously - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I have this array of objects:

```
const flights = [
    { id: 00, to: "New York", from: "Barcelona", cost: 700, scale: false },
    { id: 01, to: "Los Angeles", from: "Madrid", cost: 1100, scale: true },
    { id: 02, to: "Paris", from: "Barcelona", cost: 210, scale: false },
    { id: 03, to: "Roma", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: false },
    { id: 04, to: "London", from: "Madrid", cost: 200, scale: false },
    { id: 05, to: "Madrid", from: "Barcelona", cost: 90, scale: false },
    { id: 06, to: "Tokyo", from: "Madrid", cost: 1500, scale: true },
    { id: 07, to: "Shangai", from: "Barcelona", cost: 800, scale: true },
    { id: 08, to: "Sydney", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: true },
    { id: 09, to: "Tel-Aviv", from: "Madrid", cost: 150, scale: false },
  ];
```

What I want to do is, when I `delete` one of the objects, for those that come after the deleted object to reduce their `id` by 1.

For example, if I were to `delete` the fifth object (`id: 04`), I want the ids to go in order from 0 to 8 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) instead of going from 0 to 9 and skipping 4 (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).

This is my code currently:

```
let flightIdToDelete = 04;

for (let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++) {
    if (flightIdToDelete === flights[i].id) {
        delete flights[i];
    }
}

/* The array would then become:

const flights = [
    { id: 00, to: "New York", from: "Barcelona", cost: 700, scale: false },
    { id: 01, to: "Los Angeles", from: "Madrid", cost: 1100, scale: true },
    { id: 02, to: "Paris", from: "Barcelona", cost: 210, scale: false },
    { id: 03, to: "Roma", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: false },
    { id: 05, to: "Madrid", from: "Barcelona", cost: 90, scale: false },
    { id: 06, to: "Tokyo", from: "Madrid", cost: 1500, scale: true },
    { id: 07, to: "Shangai", from: "Barcelona", cost: 800, scale: true },
    { id: 08, to: "Sydney", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: true },
    { id: 09, to: "Tel-Aviv", from: "Madrid", cost: 150, scale: false },
  ]; */
```

My best guess would be to iterate through the objects' ids starting from the deleted one and then subtracting by 1, but I'm not too sure how to do it.

Help please!!!

Comment: "IDs" that *change* aren't usually much use as IDs.

Comment: If it's always going to be the index of the array, then you don't need the property at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `filter`, and it would be an actual simultaneous change:

```
const flights = [
    {id: 0, to: "New York", from: "Barcelona", cost: 700, scale: false},
    {id: 1, to: "Los Angeles", from: "Madrid", cost: 1100, scale: true},
    {id: 2, to: "Paris", from: "Barcelona", cost: 210, scale: false},
    {id: 3, to: "Roma", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: false},
    {id: 4, to: "London", from: "Madrid", cost: 200, scale: false},
    {id: 5, to: "Madrid", from: "Barcelona", cost: 90, scale: false},
    {id: 6, to: "Tokyo", from: "Madrid", cost: 1500, scale: true},
    {id: 7, to: "Shangai", from: "Barcelona", cost: 800, scale: true},
    {id: 8, to: "Sydney", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: true},
    {id: 9, to: "Tel-Aviv", from: "Madrid", cost: 150, scale: false},
];

const id = 4;
let count = 0;

const r = flights.filter((a, idx) => {
    const d = a.id !== id;
    count += d ? 0 : 1;
    a.id -= count;
    return d;
});

console.log(r);
```

```js
const flights = [
{id: 0, to: "New York", from: "Barcelona", cost: 700, scale: false},
{id: 1, to: "Los Angeles", from: "Madrid", cost: 1100, scale: true},
{id: 2, to: "Paris", from: "Barcelona", cost: 210, scale: false},
{id: 3, to: "Roma", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: false},
{id: 4, to: "London", from: "Madrid", cost: 200, scale: false},
{id: 5, to: "Madrid", from: "Barcelona", cost: 90, scale: false},
{id: 6, to: "Tokyo", from: "Madrid", cost: 1500, scale: true},
{id: 7, to: "Shangai", from: "Barcelona", cost: 800, scale: true},
{id: 8, to: "Sydney", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: true},
{id: 9, to: "Tel-Aviv", from: "Madrid", cost: 150, scale: false},
];

const id = 4;
let count = 0;

const r = flights.filter((a, idx) => {
const d = a.id !== id;
count += d ? 0 : 1;
a.id -= count;
return d;
});

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Live Demo **:**

```js
let flights = [
  { id: 0, to: "New York", from: "Barcelona", cost: 700, scale: false },
  { id: 1, to: "Los Angeles", from: "Madrid", cost: 1100, scale: true },
  { id: 2, to: "Paris", from: "Barcelona", cost: 210, scale: false },
  { id: 3, to: "Roma", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: false },
  { id: 4, to: "London", from: "Madrid", cost: 200, scale: false },
  { id: 5, to: "Madrid", from: "Barcelona", cost: 90, scale: false },
  { id: 6, to: "Tokyo", from: "Madrid", cost: 1500, scale: true },
  { id: 7, to: "Shangai", from: "Barcelona", cost: 800, scale: true },
  { id: 8, to: "Sydney", from: "Barcelona", cost: 150, scale: true },
  { id: 9, to: "Tel-Aviv", from: "Madrid", cost: 150, scale: false }
];

flights = flights.filter(({ id }) => id !== 4).map((obj, index) => {
    obj.id = index;
  return obj;
});

console.log(flights)
```